# How to write cellClicked for QT Table Widget in Python

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, qt-designer

How can I clicked on a Tablewidget to get the row/column informations?
If I start my GUI it crash.
The line self.tableView_movies.cellClicked(self.func_test) made the Error, what shall I change?

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
# Variables
movie_results = []

```
def setupUi(self, MyResultWindow):
    MyResultWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MyResultWindow.resize(800, 616)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MyResultWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

    self.tableView_movies = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.tableView_movies.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 331, 581))
    self.tableView_movies.setObjectName("tableView_movies")

    MyResultWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    self.retranslateUi(MyResultWindow)
    self.tableView_movies.cellClicked(self.func_test)  <----
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MyResultWindow)


def func_test(self, row,  column):
    print("T")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call method `connect` on the signal to establish the connection.

`self.tableView_movies.cellClicked.connect(self.func_test)`